# Incluir texto en un ProgressBar

Tags: vb.net, progressbar

Estoy intentando incluir un texto en un ProgressBar (que he modificado para que sea en modo vertical) de manera que iré actualizándolo cuando vaya cambiando el valor, he hecho la prueba intentando escribir el texto HOLA pero no me lo incluye de ninguna forma, el código es el siguiente:

```
    Dim gr As Graphics
    gr = Me.MyVerticalProgessBar1.CreateGraphics()
    gr.DrawString("HOLA",
    SystemFonts.DefaultFont,
    Brushes.Black,
    New PointF(Me.MyVerticalProgessBar1.Width / 2 - MeasureString("HOLA",
    SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Width / 2.0F),
    Me.MyVerticalProgessBar1.Height / 2 - (gr.MeasureString("HOLA",
    SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Height / 2.0F)))
```

Incluyo una captura para ver que no aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Donde tienes ese código? Muy probablemente lo que te está pasando es que en cuanto el progressbar incrementa su valor, se redibuja y se pierde el texto

Comment: Y si creas un label con fondo transparente independiente del progressbar y lo colocas por delante o en la posición que quieras?

Comment: Tenias razon @Pikoh, ya lo he arreglado!

Comment: @DevCodeG es otra forma de hacerlo si!

Comment: Si tenes una respuesta, podrias agregarla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal la posición final de los controles, este código te lo resolverá...

```html
Dim gr As Graphics
    gr = Me.MyVerticalProgessBar1.CreateGraphics()
    gr.DrawString("HOLA",
    SystemFonts.DefaultFont,
    Brushes.Black,
    New PointF((Me.MyVerticalProgessBar1.Width / 2) - (MeasureString("HOLA",
    SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Width / 2)),
    (Me.MyVerticalProgessBar1.Height / 2) - (gr.MeasureString("HOLA",
    SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Height / 2)))
```